# Disabled then enabled kext signing; some keys no longer work properly

Tags: keyboard, macos, user-account, root

MacOS Sierra MacBook Pro mid2012

I disabled kext signing (to use change some icons in liteicon, which I never got to), and pretty soon some of my keys didn't work like they should. I then enabled it, and rebooted it. As soon as I logged in, some keys no longer did what they should do. The keys that are affected are `i, j, k, l, m, o, u`, and I don't know if any non-letter keys are affected.

I have noticed that the `i` key functions as `cmd+o`, and some of the other keys do stuff too (but I don't know what).

Is there any way that I can fix this? This is my school computer (I'm currently doing this at school), and I really need my computer working.

SIP and root are enabled, and so is kext signing currently.

Also, idk if it matters here but Finder keeps crashing (not responding) when I do minor things like clicking on folders when logged into my user account.

Interestingly enough, this only happens on my user account, not on root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with accessibility settings. The function is called "Enable Mouse keys". It is configured in Settings - Accessibility - Mouse & Trackpad (left pane option), "Enable Mouse Keys" AND ALSO via the "Options..." button.

There is a checkbox setting "Press the Option key five times to toggle Mouse Keys". If this is active then simply pressing the option key 5 times will activate or deactivate this feature thus changing the functional mode of your keyboard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxSo1xnxL_k

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I had mouse keys enabled